# spring jdbctemplate returns 0 for last_insert_id()

Tags: java, spring

The code given below always returns zero for the last insert id. Can you please explain me what is wrong with this code?

```
JdbcTemplate insert = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        insert.update("INSERT INTO item (price, item_category) VALUES(?,?)",
            new Object[] { beverage.getPrice(), beverage.getItemCategory() });
        int id = insert.queryForInt( "SELECT last_insert_id()" );
        System.out.println(id);
        return insert.update("INSERT INTO beverage (id, name, quantity,size) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", new Object[] { id,beverage.getName(), beverage.getQuantity(),beverage.getSize() });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole code above must be wrapped in a transaction. Otherwise `JdbcTemplate` can use a different connection from the pool for all statements and `last_insert_id()` is tied to a transaction.

Either use `@Transactional` or wrap your JDBC call inside [`TransactionTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html).

Comment: @jdevelop just want to know why transactions aren't good with MyISAM?

Comment: @madhumal because MyISAM doesn't support transactions at all, so if you do some inserts - you can't do rollbacks. It's similar to enabling autocommits. However MyISAM could be faster than InnoDB.

Comment: @jdevelop: even if database does not support transactions, Spring will at least make sure the whole code block runs within a single JDBC connection.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz even if it's do so, this is not transaction at all.